# How to Connect the relation between three models via primary/foreign keys?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

The report details model should be linked to all of the employees of the company so the employees, or users in the company can view any of the desired reports that will be made by a single user/employee.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """User in the system."""
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    phone_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    license = models.CharField(default=0, max_length=50)
    signature = models.ImageField(null=True,
                                  upload_to=signature_image_file_path)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'


class Company(models.Model):
    """Company Model"""
    company_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,
                                  default=uuid.uuid4,
                                  editable=False,
                                  unique=True
                                  )
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    owner_email = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    company_addr = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    logo = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to=logo_image_file_path)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name

class ReportDetails(models.Model):
    """Report object."""
    report_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,
                                  default=uuid.uuid4,
                                  editable=False,
                                  unique=True,
                                  )
    company_id = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    user = models.ManyToOneRel.one_to_many(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    r_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

result =

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/core/models.py", line 100, in <module>
    class ReportDetails(models.Model):
  File "/app/core/models.py", line 111, in ReportDetails
    user = models.ManyToOneRel.one_to_many(User)
TypeError: 'cached_property' object is not callable
```

Ideally I am basically trying to make the company as the primary key thus that I can make a list of reports viewed by each employee of the company.

Answer (score 0):

In `ReportDetails` model, this line makes no sense,

```
user = models.ManyToOneRel.one_to_many(User)
```

You are writing it wrong. And you don't need this 'user' field at all for your purpose of the code. You have a `company_id` field that is linked to your Company model. So in the logic of your views, you can fetch the company from that field. Then from the company model, you can fetch all the employees under the company and then show data accordingly. Simple Django ORM concept. I hope this helps you.